# support for "bow" window

Tags: windows, framing

I'm installing a [Marvin Integrity "bow" window](http://www.marvin.com/integrity/windows/bay-bow-wood-ultrex?view=features-options&option=features), kind of like a bay window except it's multiple casements set in a smooth arc.  These are installed in a rectangular rough opening like any window; however, the outward bulging load cannot be cantilevered, instead needing add'l support.

There are two methods: angle or 45-degree braces underneath, or a "cable system".   No one seems to know much about the latter, including local dealers, so I'm not sure exactly how it works - sounds like it suspends the load from the overhanging rafter tails.

The window I'm getting is 5 panels, about 80" wide, and projects out 10"; my roof overhang is about 2ft.  Can anyone tell me about this cable system, and which method do you recommend ?   I'd prefer the cable - not liking the way the bracing underneath might look - if only I understood it.

Answer (score 1):

With the "cable system", there are metal rods in the frame between windows that go the full height of the window and are tied into the frame. You connect a cable to an eye at the top of the window and run it back at an angle to the wall the window is installed in, above the window. The other end of the cable is fastened to a bolt that is securely fastened to the framing of the wall (this may be a lag bolt or a through bolt, depending on how the wall is framed).

I don't think these windows have this feature however. If you go to Support > Installation Instructions for the windows you posted, you'll see this quote (emphasis mine):

> IMPORTANT: While Integrity Windows and Doors does not
>   control the style of platform support to be constructed, **all bow and
>   bay applications must have support located beneath the unit that
>   follows the angle or radius projection of the unit.** The support
>   platform MUST extend directly under the sill of the unit to provide
>   continuous support. AN INTEGRITY BOW/BAY IS NOT IN ANY
>   APPLICATION ABLE TO SUPPORT ITSELF.

So if these are the windows you're getting, it looks like you're stuck with the support under the bottom.

Comment: I agree. That's not to say, however, that you couldn't support a low-profile sill with your own cable setup suspended from sleepers spanning several trusses. There is possibly room at the front of the unit to allow cables to be hidden by exterior trim.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I think I am resigned to some kind of support underneath, but maybe not so bad, as I need some structure under there to provide insulation anyhow.